# How do you translate javas "out.println" to assembly? Without use of printf

Tags: java, linux, assembly, printf, nasm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int a = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if (i < 10) {
        a++;
      } else {
        a--;
      }
     }
     System.out.println(a);
     System.exit(0);
    }
```

This is the code that I'm going to translate to assembly code. I think ive managed to do everything except for the system.out.println(a);

I've tried almost everything, with all sorts of input to the sys_write call. I am not allowed to use the print f, but rather should use the mov command. This is the code I have right now:

```
cr equ 13
ld equ 10
STDOUT equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 4

section .bss
    a resb 1

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov [a], byte 0
    mov [a],ax
    start_for:
    cmp cx,20
    jge slutt_for
    cmp cx,10
    jge else
    inc ax
    jmp slutt_if
    else:
    dec ax
    slutt_if:
    inc cx
    jmp start_for
    slutt_for:


    mov ecx,eax    ; This is where I need help
    add ecx,'0'
    mov eax,4
    mov edx,5
    mov ebx,1
    int 80h        ; End where I need help
    mov eax,1
    int 80h
```

It's supposed to work in the debugger which I access with gdb -tui *filename*, but nothing comes out. The rest of the code does what it's supposed to, but not the out print. I've tried almost anything. Help?

Comment: [Hello World in 32-bit asm](http://www.ithania.com/asm/001/32_nasm/index.html) and [Hello World in 64-bit asm](http://www.ithania.com/asm/001/64_nasm/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int a` and `int i` are 32-bit variables, so it's appropriate to handle with 32-bit registers (`EAX` and `EDX`). In a 32-bit system you should generally avoid 16-bit registers (`AX` and `CX`). Use instead 32-bit registers or 8-bit registers (`AL`, `CL`).

You forgot to initialize `CX` and the initialization of `AX` is wrong.

The SYS_WRITE syscall (int 80h) needs in `ECX` a pointer to a string (you took an immediate character). So you must first store the character and then load a pointer into `ECX`. Also, in `EDX` you have to load the **correct** amount of characters to print.

This one works:

```
section .bss
    a resb 1

section .text
global _start
_start:
    xor eax, eax            ; a = 0
    xor cl, cl              ; i = 0

    start_for:
    cmp cl, 20
    jge slutt_for

    cmp cl, 10
    jge else
    inc eax                 ; a++
    jmp slutt_if

    else:
    dec eax                 ; a--

    slutt_if:
    inc cl                 ; i++
    jmp start_for

    slutt_for:
    add al, '0'
    mov [a], al
    mov ecx, a              ; Pointer to a

    write:
    mov eax, 4              ; SYS_WRITE
    mov edx, 1              ; Amount of chars to print
    mov ebx, 1              ; STDOUT
    int 80h

    exit:
    mov ebx, 0              ; return 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h
```